# Binding to a control's FocusState in Windows 8 Metro Style Application

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, xaml-binding

I'm using the following code to bind the `RichTextBlock.Visibility` property to another control's `FocusState` property.

```
 <RichTextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Light" 
                               Foreground="{StaticResource SwiftLightTextBrush}" 
                               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ProfessionalHeadlineInput, Path=FocusState, Converter={StaticResource FocusStateToVisibilityConverter}}" >
```

The implentation of  `FocusStateToVisibilityConverter.Convert` is the following:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    var focusState = (FocusState)value;

    return focusState == FocusState.Keyboard || focusState == FocusState.Pointer || focusState == FocusState.Programmatic ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

It may be a novice question, but why the binding is not applied when I'm 'focusing' onto a target element (`ProfessionalHeadlineInput` is a `TextBox` element) using the mouse or tab navigation?

I've inserted the breakpoint into the `Convert` method, but it is not called when I'm clicking or 'tabbing' onto the `ProfessionalHeadlineInput` TextBox.

**NB** The important part - my project is a Windows 8 Metro Style Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got an [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/49acb109-799c-4b67-8a97-403329592ed3) from Matt Small on Microsoft forum:

> OK - this is actually a bug with FocusState - it's not updating the value.  I'm filing a bug in our database.  Thank you for brining this up.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `FocusState` is `DP`, make sure it actually chages
The only reason I see here - `FocusState` may not change, everything else looks fine.
Also, try to explicitly set `Mode=OneWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

Comment: I've set the `Mode` to `OneWay`. `FocusState` is a `DP`and it is actually changed, as well as `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events are fired correctly. However the binding applies only once during the page initialization.